# Nothing pops up in mailtrap after sending emails from Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, laravel-9, mailtrap

I can't understand what's going on. I am working on a project for a month now and I've been using Mailtrap almost each day. just yesterday it was working perfectly, but now when I send an email, the page keeps loading until I get the message that says "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" but nothing shows up in the Mailtrap inbox.

The error message I am getting is also unreasonable because the `$recipient` variable contains only a single email address, and one single email won't take a whole minute to be sent.

my .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME= [hidden]
MAIL_PASSWORD= [hidden]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hello@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

mailController.php:

```
Mail::to($recipient)->send(new \App\Mail\InvitationMail($data[$userIndex],$recipient,$status,$invitation,$event,$Campaign))
            ->attach(public_path($invitation["attachmentPath"]),['as' => $invitation['attachmentName']]);
            sleep(2);
```

App\Mail\InvitationMail:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class InvitationMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $emailOfthisRecipient;
    public $CampaignStatus;
    public $invitationData;
    public $eventData;
    public $campaignData;
    public $dataRecipient;
   
    
    public function __construct($data,$recipient,$status,$invitation,$event,$Campaign)
    {
        
        $this->dataRecipient = $data;                 //^ done
        $this->emailOfthisRecipient = $recipient;    //^ done
        $this->CampaignStatus = $status;            //^ done
        $this->invitationData = $invitation;       //^ done
        $this->eventData = $event;                //^ done
        $this->campaignData = $Campaign;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Event Invitation')->view('emails.InvitationMail');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it guys.
The problem was that I am an intern in an agency, and their network was blocking smtp requests.
When I returned home, I tested it and it worked like a charm